# how to add custom mail adapter for parse server?

Tags: node.js, parse-server

I'm new to `node.js` application. I'm working on parse migration. In that application i need to use `justhost` smtp settings for mailer.

How can i achieve this?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have achieved this by using `simple-parse-smtp-adapter`.

Reference https://github.com/lcortess/simple-parse-smtp-adapter

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use [this module](https://github.com/macarthuror/parse-smtp-template) is really easy to use and also you can use it to multi language mails.

Hope that can help you.

https://github.com/macarthuror/parse-smtp-template

Comment: This is the only one that worked for me in Feb 2022.